# Why does this click function only work one time?

Tags: jquery, function, click

I have a jquery script that transforms standard checkbox markup into my custom style checkbox.  The problem is that the click function only works one time.  The checkboxes only change on it's first click.  I'm not really sure what's causing this problem...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        var cbName = $(this).prop('name');
        var cbValue = $(this).prop('value');
        var cbInput = '<input type="hidden" name="'+cbName+'" value="'+cbValue+'">';

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox checked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'">'+cbInput+'</div>';
        } else {
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox unchecked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'"></div>';
        }   
        $(this).prop('outerHTML', cbDivision);
    });
    $('div[class^="jqCheckbox"]').on('click', function(){
        var cbName = $(this).data('cb-name');
        var cbValue = $(this).data('cb-value');
        var cbInput = '<input type="hidden" name="'+cbName+'" value="'+cbValue+'">';
        if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox unchecked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'"></div>';
        } else {
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox checked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'">'+cbInput+'</div>';
        }
        $(this).prop('outerHTML', cbDivision);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: why are you using same name jqCheckbox to create one more element which will cause selector to fail

Comment: Why are you replacing existing HTML? You should manipulate element, you don't need to replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document` instead of `this` and use `$(document).on`as you are creating these elements dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // here use document instead of this
    $(document).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        var cbName = $(this).prop('name');
        var cbValue = $(this).prop('value');
        var cbInput = '<input type="hidden" name="'+cbName+'" value="'+cbValue+'">';

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox checked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'">'+cbInput+'</div>';
        } else {
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox unchecked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'"></div>';
        }   
        $(this).prop('outerHTML', cbDivision);
    });

    // here use $(document).on()
    $(document).on('click','div[class^="jqCheckbox"]', function(){
        var cbName = $(this).data('cb-name');
        var cbValue = $(this).data('cb-value');
        var cbInput = '<input type="hidden" name="'+cbName+'" value="'+cbValue+'">';
        if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox unchecked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'"></div>';
        } else {
            var cbDivision = '<div class="jqCheckbox checked" data-cb-name="'+cbName+'" data-cb-value="'+cbValue+'">'+cbInput+'</div>';
        }
        $(this).prop('outerHTML', cbDivision);
    }); 
});
```